# Yii framework. Сохранение в модель только валидных полей

Tags: yii, валидация

Столкнулся с проблемой сохранения в модель(Yii framework) только валидных полей.
Допустим есть регистрация/авторизация через разные соц. сети. С соц.сети достаем данные, которые нам нужно (на примере это модель $social), передаем их в нашу модель ($model) и хотим сохранить. Но если в нашей модели стоят правила валидации, например `firstName` - не должно содержать цифру, а $social['first_name'] - содержит цифру. В этом случае модель не пройдет валидацию и не сохранится вообще. Как сделать чтобы модель сохранилась частично, без невалидных полей(в даном случае без `firstName`) ?

```
$model->firstName = $social['first_name'];
$model->secondName = $social['last_name'];
$model->nickname = $social['nickname'];
$model->save();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Как вариант можно рассмотреть следующее:**

- В модели $social в методе [rules()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html#rules()-detail) указываем соответствующие правила валидации;
- В модели $model тоже должны быть аналогичные правила;
- Валидируем $social через [validate()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html#validate()-detail), получаем ошибки валидации;
- Записываем поля из $social->[getAttributes()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html#getAttributes()-detail) в $model-[>setAttributes()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html#setAttributes()-detail), исключая невалидные с помощью метода [getErrors()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html#getErrors()-detail);
- Сохраняем $model через [save()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#save()-detail);
- **Обязательно убеждаемся в том, что модель сохранилась!**

Примерный код:

```
$social->load(...);
$social->validate();

$attributes = $social->getAttributes(null, array_keys($social->getErrors()));    

$model->setAttributes($attributes);

if ($model->save()) {
... 
} else {
...
}
```

Случай, если $social - ассоциативный массив:

```
$model->setAttributes($social);

if (!$model->validate()) {
    $attributes = $model->getAttributes(null, array_keys($model->getErrors()));
    $model->setAttributes($attributes);
}

if ($model->save()) {
... 
} else {
...
}
```

Comment: Извините за неточность, $social - это не обычная yii-шная модель, это грубо говоря массив данных. Как вариант загнять этот массив данных в yii-шную модель и проделать ваши инструкции?

Comment: @ИгорьБаранюк Да, решение существенно не изменится, я сейчас отредактирую код